# Ошибка при попытке подключиться к SQL Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Прохожу обучение на C# разработчика. Сейчас проходим тему подключение к SQL (добавление Entity Framework в проект). Так вот после написания простейшего приложения, которое должно было создать и заполнить таблицу в MSSQl вылетает ошибка, которую ни как не получается решить своими силами. Погуглив я нашел несколько советов, как ее решить, но решить ее так и не получилось.

[image: Всплывающая ошибка]

Код приложения:

```
class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    // Объекты таблицы Users
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=NOTEBOOK/SQLEXPRESS;Database=EF;Trusted_Connection=True");
    }
}
```

Класс Program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var user1 = new User { Name = "Arthur", Role = "Admin" };
        var user2 = new User { Name = "klim", Role = "User" };

        db.Users.Add(user1);
        db.Users.Add(user2);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: _NOTEBOOK/SQLEXPRESS_ - у вас есть сервер СУБД именно с таким названием? Вы устанавливали отдельно Sql Server Express? По умолчанию с Visual Studio ставится LocalDB.

Comment: И не используйте `Database.EnsureCreated();` в конструкторе контекста.

Comment: да Sql Server Express установил отдельно. Да NOTEBOOK/SQLEXPRESS - название моего сервера

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в Вашем случае, ошибка в написании пути сервера.

Пример connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True
```

В вашем случае, нужно поменять слеш с прямого на обратный между именем сервера и именованным экземпляром: **NOTEBOOK\SQLEXPRESS**